# Flask-SocketIO Authenticate

Tags: python, flask-socketio

I want to confirm the user in flasks-socketio after users entry through the flasks-login but I get a message from the server flasks-socketio that users do not login or not logged in, though I have login via flasks-log in, so how to overcome this?

```
def disconnect():
    print ("Your Not Authenticated")


@socketio.on("my home", namespace="/home")
def on_my_home(username):
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        users[username] = request.sid
        print ("Your Was Authenticated")
    else:
        disconnect()

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var socket = io.connect("http://127.0.0.1:5000/home");
        socket.on("connect", function() {
            var username = "{{ current_user.username }}";
            socket.emit("my home", username);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Does the username of your logged in user appears on the page, right below the emit line?

Comment: appear as current_user but when I try to use 2 browser then current_user appear as a browser that opened not of the name of each user in the database

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you are saying. Using only one browser, login to your application, and then go to the page that starts the SocketIO connection. Open the source code of the page in your browser, and see how the line `var username = "{{ current_user.username }}";` appears. Does it have the correct username or not?

Comment: sorry Sir I can reply because my Internet slow, username is correct which is my own name but server socketio say that I am not logged in